# Internal Website links only working for some users

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, wordpress

We are having a very hard time trying to figure out this problem or the root cause.  Our website www. countrymusicislove .com is only correctly displaying the homepage for some users.  Anytime they click on a post, about me, etc, a 404 error page is displayed.  Everything worked fine before we moved over to a new hosting company 2 weeks ago.  I am looking for any ideas and even willing to pay someone to troubleshoot and fix this issue as no one seems to have an answer.  The entire website is done in the latest version of wordpress.

The old website address for the website is http://siteground243.com/~countr10/
And the domain name was registered through google for enom.com

Everything is now going through Arvixe.com

On my work computer, I am able to get the 404 error to appear on other pages by turning on friendly error messages.  When I turn off friendly error messages, everything seems to work.  I have tried this several times and it doesn't seem like a coincidence.

Comment: I'm willing to bet on DNS.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already gone through this. I would like to see the exact sub-status code of the error message. There has to be some configuration issue on the IIS server which is giving you this error.

404 - Not found.
404.0 - (None) – File or directory not found.
404.1 - Web site not accessible on the requested port.
404.2 - Web service extension lockdown policy prevents this request.
404.3 - MIME map policy prevents this request.
Hope this helps.

Comment: It looks like a regular 404 error.  I edited my post and added some more info at the bottom that might be helpful.

Comment: check IIS logfiles, check if your requests are actually served from IIS at all. This may be just from your browser cache. Also, if the error code is 404 that means the page is not there or the link referring to the page is incorrect/broken.

Comment: Our error logs are constantly getting errors like the following

[Fri Mar 05 13:40:06 2010] [error] [client 207.46.195.234] File does not exist: /home/cmil/public_html/2009
[Fri Mar 05 13:39:59 2010] [error] [client 82.241.206.221] File does not exist: /home/cmil/public_html/feed
[Fri Mar 05 13:39:58 2010] [error] [client 82.225.222.187] File does not exist: /home/cmil/public_html/feed